# Extract intersecting polygon from multipolygon search

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-spatial

I'm using the latest SQL Server and trying to build a query where i can search a database of spatial data and find the intersecting polygon.

The problem is that the spatial data can be of multipolygon type, and I would like to be able to return only the intersecting polygon inside it's geometry, not the entire thing.  Is this possible? Simple example below:

```
DECLARE @searchLoc geometry
SET @searchLoc = geometry::Point(@LON, @LAT, @SRID)

SELECT LocationName, <intersectingPoly?>
FROM dbo.LocationTable
WHERE LocationTable.LocGeometry.STIntersects(@searchLoc) = 1
```

Comment: i think to get just intersecting part of polygon you can use STIntersection(geometry)

Comment: This will only return the part that intersects but will potentially alter the part(clip it). See my answer on how you would do this to only extract the part of the multipolygon you need without clipping.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don't want to clip the geometry, like intersection will do, you can use a numbers table to do this. If you're unfamiliar with numbers tables you may want to look into them but they are basically just a table with an identity(1,1) column that's a clustered primary key. Populate this table with like 5000 or more values depending on your use cases.

The best way to do this is going to be to subset your Locations to be only those which for sure intersect(assuming you've built a spatial index this will help minimize runtime), and then grab the sub-part for each intersecting part. Here is code that will do that:

```
   select a.LocationName, a.geom.STGeometryN(b.number) 
    from dbo.LocationTable a 
    join dbo.numbers b
    on a.geom.STNumGeometries() <= b.number 
   and a.geom.STIntersects(@searchLoc) = 1 
   where a.geom.STGeometryN(b.number).STIntersects(@searchLoc) =1
```